# How to customize editor hotkeys in vim?

Tags: vim

I am using vim on a browser-based RDP session.  Unfortunately, my browser is realllllly particular about capturing the "ctrl-w" key combo, because of unrelated-to-my-specific-use-case security reasons.  This prevents me from using the pane feature of vim, because when I try to switch panes, my tab closes (!!!).  Is there a way to change the "pane switch" hotkey to something besides "ctrl-w" in vim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "pane switch" "hotkey" in Vim. If you want to change `<C-w>` to something else you will have to do it for every single `<C-w><something>` command:

```
nnoremap <key>w <C-w>w
nnoremap <key>T <C-w>T
...
```

Now, what `<key>` to use is left as an exercise for you.

Comment: "do it for every single <C-w><something>" EVEN BETTER!  Huzzah!

Comment: Actually, you can do `nnoremap <c-a> <c-w>` and it will work for all wincmd combos at once. Of course, if only a few are gonna be used, then it may be preferable to map them individually using single keys.